Can pilot wave theory be modified to retain locality?
My understanding is that pilot wave theory is explicitly non-local in that the guiding equation is dependant on the instantaneous positions of all particles in the universe.
Without going into any complexities involving relativity on that front, it seems like a dependence on the current instantaneous positions of all particles in the universe could be changed to being instead a dependence on the positions of each particle as they were in the past plus all their relevant wave functions. Since their past positions and past wave function states determine their future positions, it seems to me that no actual non-locality is necessary as the dependence of a guiding equation for a particular particle could all come from states that exist within the light-cone of that particle. Tho I can imagine the math might be quite a bit more complicated to do that.
Is my intuition incorrect here? If so, why is it incorrect?

No one was been able yet to formulate it that way, and I doubt anyone will. But I would be very happy if someone figures that out.

So the universe is purely deterministic?

I agree with @JonCuster This proposed modification seems to be changing the pilot wave theory to something that is essentially the super-deterministic interpretation, where the future is precisely determined by past conditions and there is no real randomness in the universe.

Pilot wave theory already doesn't have randomness. I'm not talking about super-determinism, I'm talking about reconstructing the theory so that a particle's path depends on variables within the light-cone of the particle rather than variables outside that light cone. That changes nothing about determinism and has nothing to do with super-determinism.

Bell type experiments involve setting a quantum system up in an entangled state like this:
$$|\psi\rangle=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle_1|0\rangle_2+|1\rangle_1|1\rangle_2)$$
Bell type correlations arise when you have options about what to measure on each particle, such as being able to measure:
$$X=|0\rangle\langle 1|+|1\rangle\langle 0|\\
Z=|0\rangle\langle 0|-|1\rangle\langle 1|$$
If you measure $X$ on both particle 1 and particle 2 and compare the results they will match, if you $Z$ on both particle 1 and particle 2 the results will match. If you measure $X$ on one and $Z$ on the other the results will only match with probability 1/2.
If you can measure either $X$ and $Y$ on particle 1 and either $-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(X+Z),\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(X-Z)$ on particle 2 such measurements are sufficient to produce a result that can't be explained by a local, classical theory, see Section 2.6 of "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information" by Nielsen and Chuang.
I will use the term sprinkle to refer to the particles that pilot wave theory adds to quantum theory. If sprinkle 1 is dependent on $|\psi\rangle$ and on the state of sprinkle 2 when they last interacted that doesn't help because neither the past state of sprinkle 2 nor $|\psi\rangle$ tells you what observable will be measured on both systems.
There is a local theory that explains Bell correlations. The equations of motion of quantum theory without any sprinkles or collapse are local. The observables of a system can come to depend on the observables of another system only through local interaction. The correlations are explained by decoherent channels, such as wires carrying measurement results, carrying quantum information that can't be accessed by measurements on those systems alone: locally inaccessible information
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007
https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223
When the systems carrying the measurement results interact the locally inaccessible quantum information in each system causes the results to match up in the appropriate way.

decoherence basically means many worlds interpretation

Thanks but this answer seems to be attempting to answer the title question without reading the body of my post. I understand the explanation you're giving, but it doesn't address the fundamental nonlocality of the guiding equation in deBroiglie-Bohm theory.

@PatoGalmarini I don't know where that even comes from. Decoherence is the interaction with ONE real system that has a very large configuration space. MWI is the non-interaction with an INFINITE number of copies of the universe. Decoherence is maximally physical, MWI is maximally unphysical.

@FlatterMann in my understanding the wave function never collapses due to decoherence (unless you used a modified version of QM), so the cat is still both alive and death in different branches

@PatoGalmarini The wave function never collapses to begin with. It's not a physical quantity but a mathematical abstract that describes an unmeasured quantum mechanical ensemble. That abstract ensemble doesn't change just because nature gives us one possible sample out of an infinite number of possible samples.

@PatoGalmarini Schroedinger really messed up a lot of minds with his ill-conceived polemics. Schroedinger's cat is NOT a problem of quantum mechanics. It's a problem that exists in classical physics as well and that is called Poincare recurrence. In a perfectly closed system the trajectory will always come arbitrarily close to every possible point of phase space, so not only can there be a live cat in Schroedinger's box at some time in the near infinite future, but there could also be a frog and a lump of coal. That's not physics. That's just a false approximation.

@FlatterMann The MWI is not "non-interaction with an INFINITE number of copies of the universe" since different versions of a system do interact
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033
Decoherence in the MWI suppresses interference between the different versions and for objects we see around us it makes them evolve independently to a good approximation
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189

@alanf I have never seen a second version of the universe, so you will have to excuse that I don't consider MWI science. I know where it came from, though... it's a misunderstanding of quantum mechanics by Everett (and most likely Wheeler). He didn't understand that quantum mechanics is an ensemble theory. You are correct that decoherence doesn't quite solve the problem... that's because it doesn't understand the problem. The problem is NOT that quantum mechanics has to happen in a finite volume. Quantum mechanics always happens in an open system in which irreversibility is trivial.

@alanf There is also this misunderstanding about superposition that just doesn't want to disappear. Superposition is NOT a physical property of systems. Systems are never in superposition. The mathematical quantities that describe ensembles of systems are in superposition in the same way as coordinate vectors are linear combinations of base vectors. Neither base vectors nor their linear combinations are physical objects or systems. They are human descriptions. So are wave functions. They don't exist. Nature doesn't care about them.

@FlatterMann Have you seen the core of the sun?

@FlatterMann I think I agree with you. A photon with a diagonal polarisation is presented as a mystical object that is a superposition of vertical and horizontal polarisation that cannot be described by normal physics or our intuition and we are all supposed to go woo or wow. However if an aircraft is following a diagonal path on a map, we can describe the aircraft as having a super position of vertical (North) velocity and and horizontal (East) velocity, but no one thinks there is anything woo about that and everyone understands that is not the reality of the aircrafts motion.

@alanf You can look at the core of the sun using solar neutrinos, so, yes, amazing as that sounds, that we can see. The core of Earth is a lot harder, but neutrinos can do that too... it just takes a lot more hardware.

How do you see neutrinos?
